# Rails OR query with postgres array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a tagging system in rails using postgres' array data type. I'm trying to write a `scope` that will return any posts that include a tag. So far I have this scope working:

```
scope :with_tag, ->(tag) { where("tags @> ARRAY[?]", tag) }
```

I want to extend this scope so that I can query on multiple tags at the same time, ideally something like:

```
Post.with_tags(['some', 'tags', 'to', 'query'])
```

Which would return any `Post` that have one of those tags. I've thought about making a class method to handle iterating over the input array:

```
def self.with_tags(args)
  # start with empty activerecord relation
  # want to output AR relation
  results = Post.none
  args.each do |tag|
    results = results.concat(Post.with_tag(tag))
  end
  results.flatten
end
```

but this approach smells funny to me because it's creating a new query for each argument. It also doesn't return an ActiveRecord::Relation because of `flatten`, which I would really like to have as the output.

Can I accomplish what I'm after in a scope with an `OR` query?

Comment: You're really trying to do an array intersection right? You have an array of strings in the `tags` column and an array of strings in the Ruby `args` variable and you want rows where those arrays overlap?

Comment: Yes, I think. Except I want all of the `tags` that contain any of the values in `args`, they do not need to match all of the `args`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not running the code but I think the `&&` operator does what you want:

```
scope :with_tags, ->(tags) { where("tags && ARRAY[?]", tags) }
```

Comment: is there any ability to perform case-insensitive search?